# How do I get Javascript 'addEventListener' to work on my simple animation?

Tags: javascript, events, keydown

I'm creating a game where you can switch between rocks, papers, or scissors objects. I created an animation loop to switch between the objects, by pressing keys '1','2', '3' for rocks, paper, scissors respectively. I also added event listener 'awsd' to move the object around the screen, which is not working. The 'awsd' is specifically not responding. Here is the code (with added html): `
```html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intitial- 
   scale=1.0">

  <section>
  <div class="topbar">


  <p class="key">1: Rock</p>
  <p class="key">2: Paper</p>
  <p class="key">3: Scissors</p>
</div>



 </section>


  <title>Canvas</title>

  <style>
  section {
    width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 30px;
}

.topbar {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topbar p,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
} </section>



  </style>
    </head>
```

```

```
<script>
const canvas = document.querySelector('.myCanvas');
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.setAttribute("tabindex", 0);

let objects = [];


let scissors = new Scissors(width / 2, height / 2, 30, 30, false);
let rock = new Rock(width / 2, height / 2, 30, 30, false);
let paper = new Paper(width / 2, height / 2, 30, 30, false);
objects.push(scissors);
objects.push(rock);
objects.push(paper);
scissors.setControls();
rock.setControls();
paper.setControls();



function userShape(x, y, velX, velY, exists) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.velX = velX;
  this.velY = velY;
  this.exists = exists;
}

function Scissors(x, y, velX, velY, exists) {
  userShape.call(this, x, y, velX, velY, exists);

}

function Rock(x, y, velX, velY, exists) {
  userShape.call(this, x, y, velX, velY, exists);

}

function Paper(x, y, velX, velY, exists) {
  userShape.call(this, x, y, velX, velY, exists);

}

Scissors.prototype.draw = function() {


  let scissorLength = 130
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)';

  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, scissorLength, 15);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)';

  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y - 30, scissorLength, 15);


  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y - 20, 20, degToRad(0), degToRad(360), false);
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)';
  ctx.stroke();



  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 20, degToRad(0), degToRad(360), false);
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)';
  ctx.stroke();


}
Rock.prototype.draw = function() {

  let radius = 53;
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.9)';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, radius, degToRad(0), degToRad(360), false);
  ctx.fill();
}
Paper.prototype.draw = function() {

  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 150, 150);


}
Scissors.prototype.setControls = function() {
  let _this = this;

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'a') {
      _this.x -= _this.velX;
    } else if (e.key === 'd') {
      _this.x += _this.velX;
    } else if (e.key === 'w') {
      _this.y -= _this.velY;
    } else if (e.key === 's') {
      _this.y += _this.velY;
    }

  });
};



Rock.prototype.setControls = function() {
  let _this = this;

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'a') {
      _this.x -= _this.velX;
    } else if (e.key === 'd') {
      _this.x += _this.velX;
    } else if (e.key === 'w') {
      _this.y -= _this.velY;
    } else if (e.key === 's') {
      _this.y += _this.velY;
    }

  });
};

Paper.prototype.setControls = function() {
  let _this = this;

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'a') {
      _this.x -= _this.velX;
      _this.exists = true;
    } else if (e.key === 'd') {
      _this.x += _this.velX;
      _this.exists = true;
    } else if (e.key === 'w') {
      _this.y -= _this.velY;
      _this.exists = true;
    } else if (e.key === 's') {
      _this.y += _this.velY;
      _this.exists = true;
    }

  });
};
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.key === '1') {
    rock.exists = true;
    paper.exists = false;
    scissors.exists = false;


  } else if (e.key === '2') {
    rock.exists = false;
    paper.exists = true;
    scissors.exists = false;


  } else if (e.key === '3') {
    rock.exists = false;
    paper.exists = false;
    scissors.exists = true;
  }
}

function loop() {
  ctx.fillRect(this.x - 100, this.y - 100, this.x + 100, this.y - 100);
  ctx.clearRect(this.x - 100, this.y - 100, this.x + 100, this.y - 100);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
    if(objects[i].exists){

      objects[i].draw();

    }
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);

};
loop();



function degToRad(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
};
  </script>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: Why is your loop constantly reassigning a listener to `window.keydown`?

Comment: I added the html. I also changed document.addEventListener = function to just document.addEventListener ('keydown, function). I also took window.keydown outside of the loop. The animation is still not working

Comment: Where are `rock`, `paper` and `scissors` defined? In the loop you call the `setControl()` method which will add a new event listener each time the loop runs, which will be 60 times per second. Make sure that event listeners are only added once, outside of the loop.

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier. I added the rest of the code to clarify, including how I defined the objects. Your advise worked. Now, what if I want all 3(rocks, paper, and scissors) to move by awsd?

Comment: The html has many syntax errors and no script tag included. We need to know where and how this JS is included in your html. There are missing end tags for at least <head> and<html>, missing opening tag for one of the `section`, missing `body`, and `<title>` is mixed into a section while it should be in `head`. First step to get this working is to fix your html.

Comment: You can edit your html with three backticks ( ```) and the word `html` to tell the parser which language you're writing. End the block with three new backticks.

Answer (score 0):

I would just put all of you `keydown` request into an event listener instead of trying to tie the listener to each object prototype. All you need to do then is check to see if it exists and if it does then you can move the shape.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector(".myCanvas");
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.setAttribute("tabindex", 0);

let objects = [];

let scissors = new Scissors(width / 2, height / 2, 30, 30, false);
let rock = new Rock(width / 2, height / 2, 30, 30, false);
let paper = new Paper(width / 2, height / 2, 30, 30, false);
objects.push(scissors);
objects.push(rock);
objects.push(paper);

function userShape(x, y, velX, velY, exists) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.velX = velX;
  this.velY = velY;
  this.exists = exists;
}

function Scissors(x, y, velX, velY, exists) {
  userShape.call(this, x, y, velX, velY, exists);
}

function Rock(x, y, velX, velY, exists) {
  userShape.call(this, x, y, velX, velY, exists);
}

function Paper(x, y, velX, velY, exists) {
  userShape.call(this, x, y, velX, velY, exists);
}

Scissors.prototype.draw = function () {
  let scissorLength = 130;
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)";

  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, scissorLength, 15);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)";

  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y - 30, scissorLength, 15);

  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y - 20, 20, degToRad(0), degToRad(360), false);
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)";
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 20, degToRad(0), degToRad(360), false);
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)";
  ctx.stroke();
};
Rock.prototype.draw = function () {
  let radius = 53;
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.9)";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, radius, degToRad(0), degToRad(360), false);
  ctx.fill();
};
Paper.prototype.draw = function () {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 150, 150);
};

window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  //paper
  if (paper.exists) {
    if (e.key === "j") {
      paper.x -= paper.velX;
      paper.exists = true;
    } else if (e.key === "l") {
      paper.x += paper.velX;
      paper.exists = true;
    } else if (e.key === "i") {
      paper.y -= paper.velY;
      paper.exists = true;
    } else if (e.key === "k") {
      paper.y += paper.velY;
      paper.exists = true;
    }
  }
  //rock
  if (rock.exists) {
    if (e.key === "f") {
      rock.x -= rock.velX;
    } else if (e.key === "h") {
      rock.x += rock.velX;
    } else if (e.key === "t") {
      rock.y -= rock.velY;
    } else if (e.key === "g") {
      rock.y += rock.velY;
    }
  }

  //scissors
  if (scissors.exists) {
    if (e.key === "a") {
      scissors.x -= scissors.velX;
    } else if (e.key === "d") {
      scissors.x += scissors.velX;
    } else if (e.key === "w") {
      scissors.y -= scissors.velY;
    } else if (e.key === "s") {
      scissors.y += scissors.velY;
    }
  }
});

window.onkeydown = function (e) {
  if (e.key === "1") {
    rock.exists = true;
    paper.exists = false;
    scissors.exists = false;
  } else if (e.key === "2") {
    rock.exists = false;
    paper.exists = true;
    scissors.exists = false;
  } else if (e.key === "3") {
    rock.exists = false;
    paper.exists = false;
    scissors.exists = true;
  }
};

function loop() {
  ctx.fillRect(this.x - 100, this.y - 100, this.x + 100, this.y - 100);
  ctx.clearRect(this.x - 100, this.y - 100, this.x + 100, this.y - 100);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    if (objects[i].exists) {
      objects[i].draw();
    }
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();

function degToRad(degrees) {
  return (degrees * Math.PI) / 180;
}
```

```css
section {
    width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 30px;
}

.topbar {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topbar p,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="topbar">
    <p class="key">1: Rock</p>
    <p class="key">2: Paper</p>
    <p class="key">3: Scissors</p>
  </div>
</section>
<canvas class='myCanvas'></canvas>
```